# SQLAlchemy ResultProxy Object cannot be used twice

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am unable to understand why ResultProxy object cannot be used twice when typecasted into a list. While printing the same statement again, the query_output is an empty list.

```
query_output = con.execute("_SELECT_query_")

print(query_output)
print(list(query_output))
print(list(query_output))
```

Output:

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x0000022E18C2ACD0>
[('49',)]
[]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ResultProxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=resultproxy#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) instance wraps a DB-API cursor.  Once all the rows have been read from the cursor have been read - for example, by calling `list(my_result_proxy)` then the ResultProxy instance is exhausted, just as calling `cursor.fetchall()` twice will return an empty list on the second call.